# How to specify a return type of #'sqrt in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to enable speed optimization is SBCL 2.3.1.
Compilation of the following code:

```
(defun test (x y)
  (declare (optimize speed))
  (declare (type single-float x y))
  (+ x (sqrt y)))
```

produces the following notes:

```
; processing (DEFUN TEST ...)

; file: /var/tmp/slimeftWp5F
; in: DEFUN TEST
;     (SQRT RT-SPEC::Y)
; 
; note: unable to
;   optimize
; due to type uncertainty:
;   The result is a (VALUES (OR (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT) (SINGLE-FLOAT -0.0))
;                           &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES FLOAT &REST T).

;     (+ RT-SPEC::X (SQRT RT-SPEC::Y))
; 
; note: forced to do GENERIC-+ (cost 10)
;       unable to do inline float arithmetic (cost 2) because:
;       The second argument is a (OR (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT) (SINGLE-FLOAT -0.0)), not a SINGLE-FLOAT.
;       The result is a (VALUES (OR SINGLE-FLOAT (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT))
;                               &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES SINGLE-FLOAT &OPTIONAL).
;       unable to do inline float arithmetic (cost 3) because:
;       The second argument is a (OR (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT) (SINGLE-FLOAT -0.0)), not a (COMPLEX
;                                                                                        SINGLE-FLOAT).
;       The result is a (VALUES (OR SINGLE-FLOAT (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT))
;                               &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES (COMPLEX SINGLE-FLOAT)
;                                                         &OPTIONAL).
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 2 notes
```

If I'm understanding correctly, the generic `#'sqrt` function may return values of different types. But I'm supplying a `single-float` argument to it, is it possible somehow to specify what the return type must be `single-float`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `y` is negative, the square root will be a complex value:

```
> (test 1.5 -3.2)
#C(1.5 1.7888544)
```

If you want to restrict your floats to positive or zero values, you can use the compound type specifier:

> **single-float** *[single-lower-limit [single-upper-limit]]*

For example, as follows:

```
(defun test (x y)
  (declare (optimize (speed 3)))
  (declare (type (single-float 0.0) x y))
  (+ x (sqrt y)))
```

There is no warning in that case for me.

Comment: But also, to specify the result type of any expression, you can use the special operator `the`: `(the single-float (sqrt whatever))`.